# how to check if chkconfig failed

Tags: redhat, openfire, init.d

How do I check for "chkconfig" failing to create links?

I have four scripts in /etc/init.d (Red Hat 6) with "# chkconfig 345 88 20" and the description on the following line. For three of the scripts, the proper S88/K20 links get created in the /etc/rc[345].d directories. However, for the last one (which is the openfire startup script), the links do not get made and so openfire does not start up upon reboot. I have looked in /var/log/messages, but have not found anything related to 'chkconfig' or 'openfire'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

First check your run level and accordingly go to the run level directory in init.d.
There you will have two main types of services; those starting with a 'K' are killed during the reboot of the machine and those starting with an 'S' are started during the reboot.

If a process is running through chkconfig, it will be transferred from a 'K' state to an 'S' state.

Comment: The problem is that my links are not even getting made. So I don't know if 'chkconfig' failed somewhere and I don't know how to find that out. My workaround is to put a "chkconfig --add openfire" as part of my startup and that seems to work. I don't know why chkconfig works on my three other scripts and not this one.

Comment: What kind of links are you trying to create?

Comment: I thought that if this line was in an /etc/init.d/random: "# chkconfig: 345 99 20", then 'chkconfig' would run and automatically create the /etc/rc3.d/S99random and /etc/rc0.d/K20random (etc.) links. This is how it works for three of my startup scripts, but not the fourth one. I just need to know where to look for the error if chkconfig fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an FYI for anyone on CentOS7+, the chkconfig utility has largely been replaced by systemctl.  chkconfig --add silently fails (which is why I'm mentioning this here).